# Alias Name in New-AzSubscriptionAlias Command

Tags: azure, powershell, subscription

I am using the below command to create a new subscription in Azure, But I am a bit confused about what does AliasName means, Why cant I just put the Subscription name to create new subscription?

Also, what are the best practices for the alias name, should I just name it as a subscription name?

New-AzSubscriptionAlias -AliasName  -SubscriptionName "SubscriptionName" -BillingScope "billing details"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is new functionality in Az Powershell version 5 and later. It's `New-AzSubscription` in Az Powershell 4.8.

That said, the alias is not required, in fact, you can't even see it in the portal currently.

Since you're creating a net new subscription and not altering an existing one, I would try either using `-AliasName ""` or `-AliasName "MySubscriptionName"`.